# fill lower triangle (including diagonal) of a Numpy Array with -infinity - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, infinity

I have a 2D array as below.

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

I need it to be converted into:

```
[[-inf  2   3] 
 [-inf -inf 6]
 [-inf -inf -inf]]
```

i.e., fill the lower triangle, including diagonal, to -infinity.
How to do it using python ? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.tril_indices`:

```
m[np.tril_indices(m.shape[0])] = -np.inf
print(m)

array([[-inf,   2.,   3.],
       [-inf, -inf,   6.],
       [-inf, -inf, -inf]])
```

Suggested by @Kevin, use:

```
m[np.tril_indices_from(m)] = -np.inf
```

Note: the dtype of your array must be float because np.inf is a float.

Comment: ```m[np.tril_indices_from(m)] = -np.inf``` should also work :)